# advantage of serialization over sockets c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

currently we have integrated networking into our game, using UDP protocol. It works fine. But we are sending strings over there network to the server. "10,10,23 - 23,9,10 - 9,23,23" 
I came across that I need to serialize the data as this is the right way to do it? what are the benefits of it? does it reduces the performance? Or is sending string fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You're already serialising it.*

I think what you're asking is whether it is beneficial to [serialise to a compact, binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065980/560648) rather than human-readable strings. The answer is **yes**, since you can reduce bandwidth requirements and parsing time.

Sometimes you can simply copy the bytes that make up your objects straight into the communications media, though watch out for endianness, padding, width, alignment and other implementation-defined quantities; generally you want to define a single, universal format for your data and some translation may be required on one or more endpoints in order to express the data interchange. That said, in most cases, that's still going to be cheaper than string parsing and stringisation.

The downside is you cannot snoop on the communications channel and immediately see with your eyes what's going on, when debugging your networking.